# ElasticSearch: Indexing times out if number_of_replicas is greater than 1

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm experimenting with scaling ElasticSearch and want to increase the amount of replicas, but I am unable to index anything if the number_of_replicas is set higher than 1.

I've been able to replicate the issue with a fresh install of ES:

- Download and unzip ES
- Modify the `config/elasticsearch.yml` file and set the `index.number_of_replicas` setting to 2
- Run `bin/elasticsearch`
- Index a test document: `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/example/1' -d '{body:"Hello"}'`
- Timeout

I'm running the latest version of ES (1.2.1) on a Mac OSX 10.9.2. I've also been running ES on an Ubuntu Wheezy VM, but I encountered the same problem there. Setting the number of replicas on an index-basis (using a `PUT` request) has the same effect. It makes me feel like I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: Which java version and vendor?

Comment: Ah, and you need more than one node if set replica higher than 1. ES is a distributed system so you're running normally more than one node (nodes can be on different hardware but can also reside on the same server)

Comment: salyh: `java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)`

Comment: salyh: Really? REALLY? I added more nodes and it just worked.. now I feel really stupid, but is there an error log somewhere which could have told me this?

Comment: log/ folder contains error logs (and by default the console - if your run it in foreground mode - show also error messages. Its always also a good idea to use a ES cluster monitoring tool like http://www.elastichq.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power up more ES nodes (see my second comment)

Comment: It's funny how that's the last thing I thought would fix the issue. Thanks :D